# customized kendoMultiselect: opens for a short time by clicking internal dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I have problem with this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/ikIqI

My KendoMultiselect is customized with tag template and includes an internal KendoDropDownList. By clicking on internal select You can see the main select **opens for a short time**. Is there a way I can prevent this effect?

I have tryed with preventDefault(), stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() jQuery-methods on internal click-event, but it does not help..

Answer (score 0):

see the working example in below given link:-

http://dojo.telerik.com/ikIqI/6

Code:-

```
getGeneralMultiselect().wrapper.off("mousedown", ".internalSelect").on("mousedown", ".internalSelect", function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank You, it works.)  Additionaly e.preventDefault() on "mousedown" will prevent selection blink.  P.S.: internal dropdown looks a bit strange.. I can fix this with formatting template as a table. Is there some better way to keep standard k-dropdown styles for internal select?